# How to pass multidimensional array from controller to view page and how to access it

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anybody tell me like how can i access pass multidimensional object array from a controller to view page and how can i access those data from the view page. My requirement look like this

i have my first array

```
for($i=1; $i<=$day;$i++){
    $search_result[$i][1] = $this->photos_m->get_user_photos_by_date($this->user->_id, str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , $month, $year);
}
```

and also i need to append the values to this array like this

```
foreach($friends as $friend=>$obj){   
    $friendCount++;
    for($i=1; $i<=$day;$i++){                                      
        $search_result['results'][$j] = $this->photos_m->get_friend_photos_by_date($obj->relation_id, str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , $month, $year);
    }
}
```

the result of `$this->photos_m->get_friend_photos_by_date($obj->relation_id, str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , $month, $year);` is an object array.

Please note that i have to store the data in a multidimensional array like this

```
$search_result[0][1],$search_result[0][1] .... $search_result[n][n]
```

please check my code that i pasted above and please guide me if i have done anything wrong. If it is right please tell me how to access that data from the view page?

Comment: Hi @anoop, if any of below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment I'll post an answer and edit it :)
You're using codeigniter, right?

So if you pass an array (in your **Controller**) to your view like:

```
$data['results'] = $search_result;
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

You can then access your multi dimensional array(in your **View**) like this:

```
<?php foreach($results as $result):
print_r($result); 
endforeach:?>
```

If that doesn't work: Did you check if you got any output while doing

```
foreach($friends as $friend=>$obj){
```

I mean, did you check if $friend and $obj actually have a value? 
And more important: Did you `print_r($search_result);` after your loop? Just so see if you actually got any values in your array.